# How to save the older config/metadata file while doing rpm update

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Problem defintion: Say I'm at build X1 with rpm1 version of a pkg
that delivers file Y1 (that contains metadata). I next do rpm -Uvh
with rpm2 version of the pkg that delivers newer file Y1 (but actually
endsup overwriting the previous file). Post installing rpm2 - reboot
of the host is pending.

What I would like to do is: retain or save the Y1 until reboot happens
and ONLY then overwrite. Questions.
1. How can I do this ?
2. Will rpmsave or rpmnew features work in this? 
3. A concrete example will be really useful.

Thank you.

Comment: In other words "RPM spec files have a macro, %config, that is used to mark config files so that edits to config files won't get lost during a subsequent upgrade." - Can I expand this to any other file that I am going to package with RPM. BAsicallY I am going to carry some metadata file that gets delivered but want to use same mechanism to save during update process. There will NOT be any edits on the file. It will also not be a part of %config - stanza in the RPM specfile.

Answer (score 1):

You should mark it as:

```
%files
%config(noreplace) your.conf
```

This will preserve old config during the upgrade and the new config will be created as `your.conf.rpmnew`.
This is a time when rpm leaves you on your own.

Then you have basically two options either instruct users to reboot and then run `rpmconf -o yourpackage` to merge or replace your config.

Or, if this is a server, you can provide ansible playbook, which will upgrade packages, reboot server, and then move your.conf.rpmnew to your.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Stock RPM cannot do this. It has the `%config` macro (with some parameters available). You'll have to custom write a one-shot script and drop it somewhere to run on next boot.

There's some official Fedora guidelines [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Initial_Service_Setup#Common_Guidelines).